# javascript/jquery looping through html content and replacing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

I need help with the following.
I have a solution, in which, I receive an html content in jscript, that contains tags like:

```
<div>...
     <span style="color: #123abc">Some Text</span>...
     <span style="font-weight: 700">Some more text</span>...
</div>
```

The html can contain a large amount of different tags and texts, and several spans with the font-weight: 700.
The idea is to grab that and replace the text with *text*, so it can be copied into the clipboard and pasted in Whatsapp, so whatever is contained among * will be in bold.
The solution for this is (and is working):

```
   $.each($(txt).find("span"), function(i, v) { 
       if ($(v).css("font-weight") == "700") { 
          $(v).text(''+ $(v).text().trim() + ''); 
       } 
       return(v); 
   });
```

I can do a console.log(txt) and will show the desired text.

Now I have another set of html in which I have to do the same. But the retrieved html is different, looks more like:

```
<span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <strong><span style="color:#132449">Some Text</span>
            <span> Some other Text</span>
    </strong>
    <span style="color:#000000"> - ID:  20</span>
    <br/>
    <strong><span style="color:#f56d22">Another important Text</span></strong>
    <span style="color:#132449"> EXW ATLANTA, GA</span>
</span>
```

In this case, I need to add *, on each span that is INSIDE a   tag.
My attempt has been:

```
   $.each($(txt).find("strong"), function(i, v) { 
       $.each($(v).find("span"), function(j, w) {
          $(w).text('*'+ $(w).text().trim() + '*'); 
          return(w);
       });
       return(v);
   });
```

and

```
   $.each($(txt).find("strong span"), function(i, w) { 
          console.log(w);
          $(w).text('*'+ $(w).text().trim() + '*'); 
          return(w);
   });
```

The console.log inside, show me the * are added correctly.
However, after running that, if I do a console.log(txt), the text shows without any change in it.
It is basically the same solution, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here that does not change the text inside the variable "txt".
Can anyone help me or hint me in the right direction?
Thanks.

-- As of today 2020-Sep-22
I have tried all the things you have pointed (just 2), and none of them worked.
I am starting to believe that the issue is how the html I get (cannot change that, it comes out of a function from other party) is somehow not compatible to change this way with Javascript or jQuery. Will simply not replace in origin the  texts for whatever I set.

Comment: I see jQuery and JavaScript so I removed the jscript tag

Comment: The return statement in your `$.each` is unnecessary.  `each` methods do not return anything

Comment: Also, if you are looping over elements that are in an existing jQuery object, you should use `$(txt).find('strong span').each(...)`, and not the `$.each` version, which is intended for non-jquery object iterations.

Comment: Sure, I can change to the .each( .. ) 
$(txt).find("strong span").each(function(i,v){$(v).text('*' + $(v).text() + '*'); console.log(v)});

But still, the console.log(v), though it shows the right changes... the console.log(txt) does not, it keeps showing the original text without change.